# How can i convert xml resources to int programatically in android?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I've a xml file in drawable which looks like :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/green_button_unchecked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!--  pressed  -->
<item android:drawable="@color/green_button_unchecked" android:state_focused="true"/>
<!--  focused  -->
<item android:drawable="@color/green_button_unchecked" android:state_selected="true"/>
<!--  selected  -->
<item android:drawable="@color/gray_6"/>
<!--  default  -->
</selector>
```

I can use this in setBackgroundResource(drawable.xmlName);

As we know , setBackgroundResource() need resouceId of int type...

How can i use setBackgroundResource() by creating xml programatically if i am not allowed to use resources ??

I hope you understood my problem...
Thankyou

Comment: what do you mean? you want to use setBackgroundResource programatically?

Comment: yes , i wanted to set backgroundResource programatically without the use of xml . @UsamaAltaf

Comment: I don't think that's possible (by looking at the methods used to set the background)... Is there a reason why you don't want to use **XML**?

Comment: the XML in android resources is not XML per se - it's kind of binary XML... reader is build in native and can only read binary XML with it ... but as we know there is `setBackground` ... and you can build Drawable programatically

Comment: @SnehaSharma You could perhaps use `setImageBitmap` or `setImageUri` if that's a possibility?

Comment: @DavidLee i can't use that :(

Comment: `<selector/>` is `StateListDrawable` ... you can build it programmatically ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're creating XML Programmatically, as if you want to create a Drawable you can do that without needing XML.

Any XML file has a name, and the IDE creates a generated class that contains all the IDs of the files.

If it's a drawable, it's `R.drawable`.
For colors it's `R.color`.
For Strings `R.string`.

So if you want to set background by resource, you just use `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.file_name)`

If you don't want to use XML, you'll have to manually create the Drawable object, and use `setBackground` or `setBackgroundDrawable` instead. It is a big hassle, since there are many types of Drawables.

Vector Drawable, Gradient Drawable, Layered Drawable, Color Drawable, etc.

You'll have to figure out what you want and create it manually

Comment: It seems like the OP doesn't want to use an **XML** file to do so (which means not using `R.drawable`) based on the comments.

Comment: @DavidLee yes i don't wanted to use xml file and create the xml stuffs programatically.

Comment: Edited answer. Check it now

Comment: setBackgroundResources() need int type .. instead of using setBackgroundResource method ,  can i use setBackgroundDrawable() ??

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote in the answer

Comment: Just a note: `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah but it just invokes `setBackground`